# How can I add more than one AddAuthentication to builder.services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm new to asp core, I have implement the following to login AD identity,

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();`

and also the following to login with user name / password and add cookie,

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Auth1").AddCookie("Auth1", options => { options.Cookie.Name = "Auth1"; });`

but how can I add both authentication to allow either case to login?

I have both tested working properly but cannot add both to builder.services.

Please recommend web page reference or approach to implement this.

Comment: `.AddNegotiate().AddCookie(...)`? All `.AddAuthentication("somevalue")` does is set "somevalue" as the default, and I'm sure you can appreciate that two defaults doesn't make sense for a single application.

Comment: The documentation is always a good place to start, as there are examples and detailed explanations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: if this is not possible, then I have to use AddNegotiate to allow win user login, and manage identities and claims for users other than the win user to work temporarily, is it correct?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.

Comment: My web application allows window users access without log in, my colleague can click log out and log in with his user name and password.